# File Transfer using AllJoyN from Android to Windows

Tags: alljoyn

This question is regarding file transfer using AllJoyN

I am using the basic_client & basic_service files for Windows 64 Bit desktop machine and I was able to build and run it successfully to transfer files from Client to Service.

Also I am able to transfer files between two phones in Android using the Android sdk with the FIle Transfer sample provided which in turn uses the FileTransferComponent.

Now I am trying to make the discovery part work for the Android devices and the Desktop. THe desktop discovers the Android device but the Android device wont discover the desktop client. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Also the file transfer modules(Like OfferFile,RequestOffer) are handled by the bus in Android whereas in Windows client, there is a FileTransfer interface implemented for the same to transfer data using input-output stream. Could you please help me understand how I can achieve the same filetransfer between the two clients when their implementation is different? Or should I use a different mechanism for this purpose?

Awaiting your reply